# Dynamic Zsh auto-completions

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to write completion functions for some custom functions I wrote, but seem to be really struggling with even the most basic ones.

An example function is:

```
function eb_instances() {
    if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage eb_instances <aws profile name> <environment name>"
        echo "e.g.:"
        echo " eb_instances production kraken-prod-api"
        return 1
    fi

    aws ec2 describe-instances --filters  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"   "Name=tag:Name,Values=$2" --profile=$1 --output=json | jq -r ".Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress"
}
```

This has two positional arguments, `<aws profile name>` and `<environment name>`

I want the completion options for `<aws profile name>` to be dynamically available by running 
`sed -n -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\]/\1/p' ~/.aws/credentials | tr \\n ' '`, and the completions for `<environment name>` to be dynamically available by running another function I have called `eb_names`.

I'm finding the documentation quite sparse and difficult to follow. I've also seen the zsh-completions repo for similar commands but can't seem to find something similar to what I need.

Any help getting started would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have found zsh completions to be one of the hardest topics in computer science to wrap my brain around. Many failed attempts over many years before I started to get it. The help available online is not great.

For a command that works like `floop [ --student=<name> ] <directory>` or `floop [ -s <name> ] <directory>`

```
#compdef floop

local context state line

_arguments \
  '(--student -s)'{--student=,-s}"[student name to filter on]:student:->students" \
  "*:directory:_files -/"

case $state in
students)
    students=($(echo 'chris pat lynn paige'))
    _describe -t students "a student's name" students && return 0
    ;;
esac
```

Replace the echo command with a zsh literal array or a command that generates choices for the student option.

The `"*:directory:_files -/"` line is for the positional argument of a directory path.

There's ways to control if the option can appear more than once or always has to be a separate word (no "=") etc but this example is a pretty simple example.